# Java read json file from another jar

Tags: java, json

so Im trying to develop a "module/addon" system and I want to read a "module.json" file from all modules/addons loaded in a direcory. So I got the part with looping through the files and stuff. But I dont know how I can access that "module.json" file.
Here is what I tried:

```
    try {
        for (File file : this.modulesDir.listFiles()) {
            if(file.getName().endsWith(".jar")) {
                InputStream stream = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{file.toURL()}).getResourceAsStream("./module.json");
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                while((builder.append(reader.readLine())) != null);
                reader.close();
                stream.close();
                System.out.println(builder.toString());
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright! I fixed it by changeing the path of the file to `module.json` instead of `/module.json`

Heres the code:

```
     try {
        for (File file : this.modulesDir.listFiles()) {
            if(file.getName().endsWith(".jar")) {
                InputStream stream = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{file.toURL()}).getResourceAsStream("module.json");
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }

                System.out.println(builder.toString());
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```